# Android Nested ViewPager Disable Touch Event

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view

In my app, I have a `ViewPager`. In one of the pages, I have another `ViewPager`, in which I have disabled the swipe gestures through a custom `ViewPager` implementation:

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works well; the swipe gestures in the child ViewPager are disabled. However, the parent ViewPager cannot be swiped unless the swipe starts from the very edge of the screen. How can I make the child ViewPager ignore all touch events/pass them on to the parent view?

Comment: it is so diffrence to detect when you wipe for parent view and not childview, in your code you disable swipe on parent when child touched.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I've run into the same problem.

Comment: @theshadowchild I did! I've posted the answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer turned out to be very simple!

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That solution work for me, how about you? Since my ViewSwitcher wasn't detecting the touch event, I intercepted the touch event, called the onTouchEvent() and returned false. Here:

```
@Override 
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) { 
    onTouchEvent(ev);
    return false; 
}
```

By overriding the onInterceptTouchEvent(), I was able to intercept the touch event in the activity. Then I called the onTouchEvent() in the ViewSwitcher which handles the switching of the ListViews. And finally by returning false, it makes sure that the ViewGroup doesn't consume the event.

**Warning**: Using this function takes some care, as it has a fairly complicated interaction with View.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent), and using it requires implementing that method as well as this one in the correct way.

More information here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Comment: Is this supposed to go in the child ViewPager (NonSwipeableViewPager, in my case)? If so, it didn't work for me.